# pass retrofit response to a function or copy it

Tags: android, retrofit, response

I'm going to pass this retrofit  **response ** to a function
does somebody know :

1. how to pass it to a function ?
   or
2. how to make it public ?
   or
3. how can I copy it :

   call.enqueue(new Callback() {

   ```
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetAllJsonDatum> call, Response<GetAllJsonDatum> **response**) {
   ```

GetAllJsonDatum is a class. I'm receiving more thank 100000 records and I need to work on these data in background , Now I need to access it a function or make it public to access it outside of public void onResponse(Call call, Response response)
or make a copy of this response;
thanks

Comment: what's the problem with passing the response and what approaches have you taken?

Comment: GetAllJsonDatum is a class , I got my json response in it ,  response has more than 100000 records and I'm planning to work on it in the background, so I need need to access it in my function , this response is not public and i cant access it outside of onResponse()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer <**only for passing it to a function**> :
just make a function like this:

```
public void getMyResponse(Response<GetAllJsonDatum> response){
      // now do whatever you want with response.body() -- :)
}
```

inside your retrofit onResponse() just call :

```
getMyResponse(response);
```

that's All;